# Easiest way to print caption of Speedbutton and Button on the same line

Tags: delphi, button, drawing, delphi-7, vcl

There's a screen in my app where I've got 5 buttons in a row, one of them is a speed button which is pretty much just used for style.  They are identical height and width but the speed button prints down 1 pixel.  This really irks me as this screen is something our users see all the time.  In Delphi 2009 I believe there is a margin option for buttons, there is a margin in Delphi 7 but it only changes the left margin.  Is there a Delphi 7 way to fix this problem?  Am I erroneously re-purposing the speedbutton?

*Note, this is not a trick interview question even though it sounds like it, put your boots back on.*

Comment: You are not using visual themes, are you?

Comment: I've got xpmanifest on, but no, my development machine is winxp - no themes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `Margin` property does change the left margin of a `TSpeedButton`'s caption, but only when the `Layout` property is set to `blGlyphLeft`, which it *is* set to by default.

Change `Layout` to either `blGlyphTop` or `blGlyphBottom`, and you will be able to adjust, correspondingly, the top or the bottom margin of the caption.

Answer (score 2):

With five buttons in a row together, trhe user would expect that they all work in a consistent manner. I would counsel against mixing TButtons and TSpeedButtons in the same group. Replace the TSpeedButton with a TButton, and then deal with the style issue (whatever that is) separately.